# Question about constrained critical point

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbf R^n, n \ge3$ and $K$ be the Green operator.
Define the functional
$$
J(u)=\frac{1}{2}\langle Ku,u\rangle,\quad u \in H^1_0(\Omega)
$$
Now define $M=u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$, $\|u\|=1$: I want to show that $z \in M$ is a constrained critical point of $J$ on $M \iff z $ is an eigenfunction of K with associated eigenvalue $\lambda=\langle K'(u),u\rangle$.

Not really sure where to start here

Comment: For the slower ones here like me, what’s the Green operator? Are you assuming it’s the Green operator associated with some unstated elliptic operator?

Comment: I'm slow too, but yes. So $K(h)$ would be the weak solution to the Laplace equation with right hand side $h$

Comment: @daw what do you think?

Comment: if you meant $\lambda=<J'(u),u>$ then I think it should go like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient#Formulation_using_Lagrange_multipliers)